# Backslash is added to JSON before double quote

Tags: python, json

As a json response I got it from server

```
{"Data":["{\"item1\": \"value1\",\"item2\": \"value2\"}"]}
```

I used

```
a=json.loads(response)
print(a)
self.write(a)
```

From terminal I saw

```
{u'Data':[u'{"item1": "value1", "item2": "value2"}"]'}
```

From postman it's like

```
{"Data":["{\"item1\": \"value1\",\"item2\": \"value2\"}"]}
```

I need as

```
{"Data":[{"item1": "value1","item2": "value2"}]}
```

I know all this format are right but I prefer the last format in postman. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question boils down to: "I need to take this valid JSON and make it *invalid* JSON" So I suspect that's not really what you want to do.

Comment: Separately: Whatever it is that's producing that JSON is almost certainly broken, so that's where I'd be looking to fix it. The JSON is valid, but what it defines (an object with a single property whose value is an array with a single string in it, which itself contains JSON) is almost certainly not what it's meant to define.

Comment: You appear to have a string containing JSON, inside your JSON. Your expected output is *broken* JSON however. Why not turn this into `{"Data":[{"item1": "value1", "item2": "value2"}]}`? E.g. decode the embedded JSON and replace the string with the result.

Comment: It is the valid JSON string format. If you'll do `json.loads`, you will get rid of these ` \ ` with `"`. You need not to change anything in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below and it works...

```
content = json.loads(content)['data']
temp = []
for values in content:
   jstr = json.loads(values)
   temp.append(jstr)
val = {"data": temp}
self.write(json.dumps(val))
```